# Auth.RegistrationHandler fails when creating Account

Tags: single-sign-on, dml, person-accounts

lately i am facing wierd issue.
I've created SSO for my community and till some point it worked fine.
Lately I've found out it is failing when creating Person Account and I have no idea why.
Code is failing at insert account and no error is returned...

code is

```
global User createUser(Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){
    System.debug('createUser');
    User contextUser;
    
    if(canCreateUser(data) && data.attributeMap.containsKey(AUTH_AzureB2C.NETWORK_KEY)) {
        Id contactId = createPersonAccount(data);
        contextUser = createUserRecord(data, contactId);
    }
    return contextUser;
}

private Id createPersonAccount(Auth.UserData data){

    Account acc = new Account();
    Id personAccId = APP_UTL_RecordType.getRecordTypeId('Account', 'PersonAccount');
    acc.FirstName = data.firstName;
    acc.LastName = data.lastName;
    acc.PersonEmail = data.email;
    acc.RecordTypeId = personAccId;
    insert acc;

    Contact[] contacts = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE AccountId =: acc.Id];
    
    if(contacts.size() != 1){
        throw new PP_SRV_RegHandlerException('Invalid account config!');
    }
    return contacts[0].Id;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: turn on the debug logs to see why it failed?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava already done, no logs at all. after insert it just close transaction without error. Like stated in last sentence before code example.

Comment: I would cross verify I have logs Turned on for right user! Hopefully that helps. Else I suggest raise a salesforce support case!

Comment: Reg Handler is always in proper context, it would be super hard to have logs setup wrong :P I've already rise case, since I have no clue whats going on with this :(